# regular expression javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following types of query string. It could be anyone of the below.

> index.html?cr=33&m=prod&p=ded
>
> index.html?cr=33&m=prod&p=ded&c=ddl&h=33&mj=ori

From the above query string, i wanted to extract only **m & p "m=prod&p=ded"**.
Otherway to do is split and get, that i have already done it.
But I wanted to achieve it using regular expression.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Why use regular expressions for this? Seems overkill for such a simple task.  Especially given that you can't reuse the code anywhere else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
(?<=&)m=[^& ]*\&p=[^& ]*
```

**[In javascript , It doesn't support `?<=` positive Lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945502/javascript-regex-positive-lookahead-giving-me-syntax-errors)**.

So you can use the following code ( in javascript ):

```
var s="index.html?cr=33&m=prod&p=ded"
s.match(/m=[^& ]*\&p=[^& ]*/g)
```

Refer **[Regexp101](http://regex101.com/r/bB5aL3)**

Answer (score 0):

If both query parameters come one after another then you you can use:

```
url.match(/[?&]m=([^&]*)&p=([^&]*)/i);
```